# VBA 2 timestamp in same excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get a timestamp in column B when I enter text in column A and a separate timestamp in column D when I enter text in column C.

I have found this VBA code which works perfectly for 1 timestamp, but I'd need help to make it valid with 2 separate timestamp within the same sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
xCellColumn = 1
xTimeColumn = 2
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
       Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.enableevents = false

If Target.Text <> "" Then

Select case Target.Column
Case 1, 3 ' columns A and C for now, add more as needed.'
Cells(target.row, target.column + 1) = Now() ' +1 as column with timestamp always seems to be 1 column to the right of the newly entered value'
End select

End If
Application.enableevents = true

End Sub
```

Code above implicitly refers to ActiveSheet. Timestamp will be entered on any sheet that is active. Consider fully qualifying the workbook and worksheet.

Comment: FWIW - the unqualified `Cells` in that code won't refer to `ActiveSheet` by default - it will refer to the sheet in which the code resides, so there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The `Offset` property is your friend:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Text <> "" Then
        'Check if column A or C was updated
        If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 3 Then
            'Disable events to stop recursive calls
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            'Place the date one column to the right
            Target.Offset(, 1).Value = Now()
            'Re-enable events
            Application.EnableEvents = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```